# Agreggating multiple category columns in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this table in my postgreSQL db that I need to aggregate in categories.

The table called "table1" looks like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Volks | 200 |
| Apple | Volks | 350 |
| Lime | BMW | 200 |
| Apple | BMW | 200 |
| Lime | BMW | 400 |

I want the output to look like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Volks | 550 |
| Apple | BMW | 200 |
| Lime | BMW | 600 |

I've tried using groupby and sum(Column C) but it didn't worked out.

```
SELECT distinct     Column A, Column B, sum(Column C) as "Sum of C"
        
GROUP BY Column A, Column B, Column C       
        
FROM public.table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be aggregating *and* grouping the same column, and *distinct* is irrelevant given a *group by* already results in distinct groups; your syntax is also wrong, that query would result in an error as *From* must precede *Group By*.

However you can use *distinct* in an aggregation, like so:

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, sum(distinct Column_C) as "Sum of C"
FROM public.table1
GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B;
```